# How to count calls to ASP.NET Web API POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to count the number of calls to the post method in Web API?

For example: I want to disable user if he 3 times enters  wrong username and password combination.
So after third call in a row, of the post method of Web API controller I want to do something (for example I will disable user somehow or something else).

How to count this calls to API controller method? Is there any already define property or method for this case?

UPDATE:

This is my Web API method:

```
[Route("login")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LoginUser(Login model)
{
    using (AuthRepository repo = new AuthRepository())
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        string deviceId = rgx.Replace(model.DeviceId, "");
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var user = await repo.FindUserAsync(deviceId, model.PIN);
        var tokenServiceUrl = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + request.ApplicationPath + "/Token";

        if (user != null)
        {
            MatrixLogManager.Debug("User " + model.DeviceId + "successfully logged in on MatrixSTS.");
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                                                {
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", deviceId),
                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.PIN)
                                                };

                    var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
                    var tokenServiceResponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenServiceUrl, requestParamsFormUrlEncoded);
                    var responseString = await tokenServiceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var responseCode = tokenServiceResponse.StatusCode;
                    var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(responseCode)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(responseString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    };

                    return responseMsg;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MatrixLogManager.Error("Error: ", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                //IF LOGIN FAILD I WOULD NEED TO COUNT SOMEHOW THAT ONE CALL WAS UNSUCCESSFUL, AFTER THIRD I WILL BLOCK USER, BUT ONLY IT HE MAKES SAME MISTAKE 3 TIMES IN A ROW. 
               //Adding simple int counter didn't worked for me.
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've been trying using simple int counter, but no success...It counts it only for the first time, after next call value remains same...

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sure, I will update my post right away...:)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov So method is little bit unreadable, but the focus is on the part where I left a comment. In else part of the loop...we don't have any interest in if part of the loop, cause it will be used only if user logged in successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save this stuff in the DB in a sub table called let's say UserInvalidFailureLogins:

The table will have a foreign key to the userId and will have a counter value.

When a user tries to login, you first check how many failures the users has and
if he exceeded the threshold then don't let him login until you reset the number of attempts.

If the user fails a login, you increment the counter by 1.

Comment: Hvala Amire :) I like this approach, and gonna try it too, cause I need to keep this value in database anyhow. @amirpopovich

Answer (score 1):

One simple way you could implement this is keeping a static `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which maps users to the amount of times they've attempted to log-in. Note this can bloat memory quite a bit depending on the number of users and how long you want to keep their counting status:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> loginAttemptsByDeviceId = 
                                                new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

And then add this to your `else` clause:

```
else
{
    int loginAttempts;
    if (loginAttemptsByDeviceId.TryGetValue(deviceId, out loginAttempts)
    {
        loginAttemptsByDeviceId[deviceId] = ++loginAttempts;
    }
    else
    {
        loginAttemptsByDeviceId.Add(deviceId, 1);
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password.");
}
```

And of course checking the value prior to logging the user in:

```
int currentUserAttempts;
if (loginAttemptsByDeviceId.TryGetValue(deviceId, out currentUserAttempts) && 
                                        currentUserAttempts == MaxLoginThreshhold)
{
   // Return some error to the user.
}
```

This assumes a `DeviceID` is a unique identifier per user. If it isn't, use a value which will uniquely will identify your users.
Note i would advice you for the long term, to keep this data persistent somewhere (if needed). Also note that this doesn't take into account concurrent requests which may be attempted. If that is an issue, consider using a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead and locking in relevant places.

Comment: thanks for answer, I will try it right away... My goal is to keep this value somewhere in database, because it is possible that will will need to check it in some other calls :) @yuvalitzchakov

Comment: @nemo_87 Then create table mapping users to their attempts, and query that prior to trying to log the user in. That would be a more appropriate long-term approach.